# How to use additional Pico i.MX7D pins on JP2 bus

Tags: android-things

According to the pinlayout here:
https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/imx7d-pico-io.html

there are 3 additional set of pins besides the main raspberry pi like 40 pins. They are on buses J9, J2, J1.

I am attempting to use GPIO2_IO01 on JP2, but after setting the pin high both in android things app and from command line tool, the pin never turns on. I can verify the 5v pin is working on the JP2 bus, but no other pins.

Comment: I notice that the name of the pin appears twice, one in the JP2 section and once in the main section, so probably you are switching the main GPIO2_IO01,

Comment: Also, I remember reading somewhere that those pins are linked to some jumper configuration as they are duplicates of the main set and if you change the jumpers the JP1 and JP2 section gets enabled and the other gets disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The I/O pins on the additional breakouts (JP1/JP2) are connected to the same signals as the main 40-pin connector. No additional configuration is needed in hardware or software to route the signal. The following `pio` commands will trigger the output to both states:

```
# Output HIGH
$ pio gpio GPIO2_IO01 write 1

# Output LOW
$ pio gpio GPIO2_IO01 write 0
```

Because the signals are shared between the connectors, if you have a HAT installed or other components connected to the same line (in this case, pin 29 on J8), something else may be keeping the signal from visibly changing.